# ¿Cómo poner activo un botón en react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un panel de control, en mi menú el problema es que no estoy trabajando como de costumbre con un `class component`, no con `react hooks`, así que es complicado para mí

anteriormente en el componente de clase he realizado esta función:

```
class Technologies extends Component {
  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="section-7">
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleChange(false)}
          className={`btnT _1 ${this.state.checked === false}`}
        >
          FACIAL RECOGNITION
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
          className={`btnT  ${this.state.checked === true}`}
        >
          OBJECT DETECTION
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Necesito activar el boton en el nuevo codigo

```
export default () => {
  const [pantalla, setView] = useState(<RealTime />)
  let cambiarpantalla = View => {
    setView(<View />)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="border-primary border-l-2 shadow-active "
        onClick={() => cambiarpantalla(RealTime)}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center  cursor-pointer mx-4  p-4 border-b border-line">
          <Real />
          <p className="ml-3">Real Time</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => cambiarpantalla(Analitycs)}>
        <div className="flex items-center  cursor-pointer  p-4 mx-4 border-b border-line">
          <AnalitycsS />
          <p className="ml-3">Analitycs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="overflow-auto">{pantalla}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

no sé cómo hacer que el botón haga clic en él y cambie la pantalla para que se active, la clase está shadow-active

Answer (score 0):

Los hook deben escribirse con functions y no con arrow functions ya que estas carecen de contexto

deberia funcionarte solo con ese cambio